# Can tf.transform handle viewfs:// path?

Tags: tensorflow, hdfs, apache-beam, tensorflow-transform

I find after apache beam 2.5.0, the hdfs path can be recognized by beam's python sdk.
But in "/python2.7/site-packages/apache_beam/io/hadoopfilesystem.py", the support schema is only "hdfs". When i loaded a viewfs path, i got this error:

**ValueError: Unable to get the Filesystem for path viewfs://hadoop-meituan/ghnn01/user/hadoop-poistar/huangshangzhi/sentiment_analysis/data/train_example.txt**

Could anyone give me some advice about use tf.transform to read an file in viewfs filesystem, i really appreciate it.
Thank you!